# Can you change the display the 'ping' command in the Terminal on a Mac?

Tags: macos, unix, terminal, ping

Is there a way to customize the display of the 'ping' command?

It's a bit superfluous, but I'd like to customize it to be 1) easier to read and 2) require less screen real estate.

Current ping:

```
64 bytes from 69.169.182.80: icmp_seq=31 ttl=61 time=9.168 ms
64 bytes from 69.169.182.80: icmp_seq=32 ttl=61 time=0.967 ms
```

Goal:

```
31 from 69.169.182.80: 9.168 ms
32 from 69.169.182.80: 0.967 ms
```

Or an even simpler version:

```
31: 9.168 ms
32: 0.967 ms
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can try using `awk`:

`ping 69.169.182.80 | awk '{ gsub("time=", "") ; gsub("icmp_seq=",""); print $5": " $7 " "$8 }'`

Then You can place this line in Your `~/.bash_profile` file:

`function pingq { ping $1 | awk '{ gsub("time=", "") ; gsub("icmp_seq=",""); print $5": " $7 " "$8 }'; };`

And later use it like:

`pingq 69.169.182.80`